# How can I get a file to autorun before I run any command in ipython?

Tags: python, ipython

I have a python file that holds a bunch of functions that I'm continually modifying and then testing in ipython.  My current workflow is to run "%run myfile.py" before each command.  However, ideally, I'd like that just to happen automatically.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use rlwrap for this, write a filter! Just define an `input_handler` that adds `%run myfile.py` to the input, and an `echo_handler` to echo your original input so that you won't see this happening (`man RlwrapFilter` tells you all you ever wanted to know about filter writing, and then some).

But isn't it more elegant to solve this within ipython itself, using `IPython.hooks.pre_runcode_hook`?

```
import os
import IPython
ip = IPython.ipapi.get()

def runMyFile(self):
    ip.magic('%run myFile.py')
    raise IPython.ipapi.TryNext()

ip.set_hook('pre_runcode_hook', runMyFile)
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any elegant way. This is the ugly way. Run:

```
rlwrap awk '{print "%run myfile.py"} {print} {fflush()}' |ipython
```

This reads from STDIN, but prints the command you wanted before each command. `fflush` is there to disable buffering and pass things to ipython immediately. `rlwrap` is there to keep the readline bindings; you can remove it if you don't have it, but this will be less convenient (no arrow keys, etc.).

Mind that you will have to type your commands before the `ipython` prompt appears. There might be other more annoying things which break, I haven't tested thoroughly.